# How can I grab a DIV with no class name or ID or any attributes using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri (with Rails) to try and parse [this site](https://www.rotoworld.com/basketball/nba/depth-charts) and Nokogiri is not cooperating.  I made it all the way down the HTML chain using css selectors and everything was working, and then I encountered a plain DIV with no class name or ID.  I need to access the content inside this div but cannot do it. Also, in place of this div with no class or ID, Nokogiri is returning me a div with an ID name that is not present anywhere if you inspect the live site.

[structure of the HTML document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ5uA.png)

In my picture, I have made it inside the div with the id="depth-chart-page-wrapper", but I need to get to the div with the class="depth-chart-wall", but it is wrapped in a plain div with no class or id or any attributes, and I cannot find a way to get a hold of this element.

So far this I've used this statement:

[This is my Nokogiri scraper in Ruby on Rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9g3R.png)

and my result returns me this:

[What nokogiri is returning to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OpWQ.png)

My result is saying that the div with class "block__content" has three children:

1. h1 with class "block__title"
2. Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc184f8aa18 "\n"
3. div with id="rw-depth-chart-value"

But if you look at the structure of the HTML on the site you should only see two:

1. h1 with class "block__title"
2. the div with no class name or id

As I said above, if you inspect the site you will see there is no element in the whole site with an ID of "rw-depth-chart-value".  Why is Nokogiri returning me this value and why can't I access the plain div the same way I've been able to access everything else up to that point?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself as text - not as screenshots. If you know the position of the element you can use css pseudo selectors. `:first`, `:nth-child`, `:nth-of-type` etc. You also don't have to chain a million calls to `.css`. If an element has an ID it should be unique on the page. You should'nt have to slog all the way up the tree to get there.

Comment: @max, I tried to include the code as best I could but stack overflow kept telling me it wasn't formatted correctly, even when I was including it in a code block.  Also, the div I want to access does not have an ID. And, I would use the pseudo selectors but for some reason Nokogiri is returning me something different than what is on the page

Comment: Yeah I got that. What you don't understand is that doing `.css('#foo').css('.bar').css('#baz')` is pointless. You can just just start at `#baz` instead. The page might also be malformed. This kind of scaping is extremely brittle and I would not recommend it unless its for learning or shits and giggles.

Comment: @max, I am learning, I'm finishing up my first web dev course.  And I appreciate the tip, noted on not using long chain calls. Even if the page is malformed, does it make sense for Nokogiri to return me a DIV that doesn't seem to exist when I inspect the page?

Comment: Yes. If the page is malformed the browser just does its best at making sense of it. Thats what you see in the inspector. It does'nt appear to be that bad though https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rotoworld.com%2Fbasketball%2Fnba%2Fdepth-charts

Comment: @max, yeah I didn't think it would be that bad since it's a professional site.  So why in the world can I not see the DIV with no class or id as a child of the div with an id of "depth-chart-page-wrapper"? Although my chain was brittle like you said, it was working up to that point, and I was able to see the children of every other element I parsed. Sorry if I'm asking any stupid questions.

Comment: Its there in the browser as well. Run `document.querySelector('#depth-chart-page-wrapper>div')` in the browser console. You seem to have gotten hung up on the idea that you need to go down step by step though. If what you want is inside that div you can just write selectors that go straight to what you want. For example `'#depth-chart-page-wrapper .team-listing-banner__name'` will give you the names of all the teams. Thats kind of the point of CSS selectors.

Comment: @max, yeah I never had any problems getting to it when working in the browser console.  My issue is in my Rails application, I am using Nokogiri to try and scrape info off this page, and I am not able to get to that classless/id-less DIV in there, even though I was able to go down the whole chain just fine up until that point. That's my question, it all works fine in the browser, but I am not getting the same results when working in my app.

Comment: Ah. Now I get whats going on. Turn JS off in your browser and then open the page. Thats what Nokogiri sees. The content you're looking at in the inspector is loaded with Ajax. Nokogiri is not a browser and does not run javascript.

Comment: In order to scrape this page you would have to use selenium or a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). I would suggest that you find another less complicated project.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Also, "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)".

Comment: This question is in the process of being closed because it doesn't meet the guidelines. Please remove links to pictures of code or other require resources, and place the minimal code and input data into the question itself, and provide the required output or results. The links above will help guide you.